# What is the history of clean rings?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, terminology, idempotents

We recall that a ring is called a clean ring if each element is the sum of an idempotent and a unit.

Is there someone who can explain to me the history of the emergence of the definition of a clean ring?  Why does the word "clean" appear in the definition of a clean ring?

Comment: I believe (but may be wrong) that the first use of the term is [here](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1977-229-00/S0002-9947-1977-0439876-2/S0002-9947-1977-0439876-2.pdf).  No explanation for the coinage is provided.  One can see where the property of being "clean" means that various constructions go through without any hitch, so perhaps that's what motivated the term, but beyond that, you'd have to ask the author.

Comment: Per site policy, comments should only be used to clarify, not answer the question. See **[How do comments work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19756)** for more information

Comment: @lulu Ok thank you for your sugestions.

Answer (score 2):

In

> Nicholson, W. Keith, and Yiqiang Zhou. "Clean rings: a survey." Advances in ring theory. 2005. 181-198.

It is stated that

> This notion was introduced by Nicholson in [24] in 1977 in a study of exchange rings.

Where reference 24 is

> Nicholson, W. Keith. "Lifting idempotents and exchange rings." Transactions of the American Mathematical Society 229 (1977): 269-278.

The name is, as far as I can tell, just an adjective selected at the time to use for reference.  The term "exchange ring" though, is definitely suggestive of its defining property.

I'd also refer to these two references for the overall development of clean rings.

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much.

Comment: Clean answer...

Comment: I need to find an interesting subclass of clean rings that I can call "squeaky"